# Need help creating 2 identical databases in SQL Server / MongoDB (with hierarchy) (in C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm creating a simple app that will let me test SQL Server vs MongoDB query speed (in C#). For that I need to create two identical and fairly big databases (let's say 1 mil records each) with some hierarchy involved.

I'm aiming for something quite simple here, each entity would having e.g. id, name, and 2-3 categories to search by (e.g. color, shape, whatever). Of course a tree structure is a must, something like a directory tree with the possibility of one entity to be a child to many.

Anyone has some simple idea on how to create and populate 2 databases like this?

I'm thinking of creating both databases at the same time using some huge iteration in C# and putting random values in both, rather then creating one database and merging it to the other one afterwards.

Thx in advance

Comment: 1M records can be handled easily by sql databases. No-sql databases like mongoDB are more suitable for huge (instead of big) amount of data. Consider no-sql databases carefully because they are not user-friendly as sql databases, you'll need to design a good document-model, develop mapreduce functions, etc etc...

Comment: If you create identical data structures, you'll probably find your design better suits one database or the other.  Benchmarking of this sort isn't overly meaningful as there are considerations beyond raw query speed.  The MongoDB wiki has some information on design patterns for [Trees in MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB).

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB, such as several NoSql databases out there, are non-relation databases, so you can't really compare them, they are target to different case scenarios.

What I do is I have an Admin interface that is hooked up to a MS SQL instance, and when the user hits **Publish** I gather all information from 25 different tables and create a single record with the relevant data that I need to run the LIVE website.

There are NoSQL methods, like [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) that allow you to join document collections, but it will never be like a JOIN in a relational database.